# How to use threading with a list and assign workers?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I am using Python Requests to check if a proxy is working or not. I have them loaded inside a .txt file in the format of IP:PORT. I have then set up threading, using the Threading module, and it works. One problem - It runs over the same IP:PORT on every thread. Once all threads have done the first line, it moves onto the second. I want to make each thread try a different IP:PORT until all of them have been checked.

I have searched around but can not find what I am looking for. I have actually been stuck with this for a couple of weeks.

```
import requests
import threading

def ip():

    with open('ip_found.txt', 'r') as i:
        iport = [x.strip().split(':', 1) for x in i]

   postIt = { 'ip' : ip, 'port' : port }

    r1 = requests.post(URL"",data=postIt)

for _ in range(2):
    for ip, port in iport:
        t1 = threading.thread(target=ip)
        t1.start()
        t2 = threading.thread(target=ip)
        t2.start()
```

Comment: You need to post the code of a [mre] — what you currently have in your question isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem here and I also see another potential problem.

One way of doing this is to read the IP:PORTs first and store them into a queue. That way, your threads don't overlap on the same IP:Port bc each thread would take from the first. (Make sure to use a mutex/lock)

The other issue that I'm seeing is that you're not keeping track of your threads. All I see is you creating two threads, starting them, then forgetting them once the for loop iterates. This code might not really be a problem as pinging an IP:Port probably doesn't take a lot of time for a single thread, but if your function starts to bloat, you might have issues.

Comment: Could you perhaps give me an example? I have tried again to understand how to create a queue, and split up the IP:PORT and make sure each worker is trying a different line